# Sending Email from gmail from localhost through Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Sometimes following code sends Email,Sometimes i get SMTP Exception saying "failure in sending Email".Why is this happening? following is the code i have written.Plesae tell me why sometime i get email sent and sometime why i get Exception.

```
 StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
 mailBody.Append("Hi <br/>")
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com");
 message.Subject = "Subject";
 message.Body = mailBody.ToString();
 SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{ UserName = "from@gmail.com",
  Password = "password"
 };
 smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;
  smtpclient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Check inner exception, what does it say?

Comment: Hi Rex,                                                                                          InnerExecption is:'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.But Why this code is allowing to send mail sometime why it is giving me execption other time.

Comment: hi  Michael Rudner Evanchik,                                                                                are u telling me change port no from 587 to 465.Its google SMTP port Number